# Ap-hotspot not creating in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, hot-spot

I installed ap-hotspot in kubuntu 13.10 and it was working but then I upgraded my os to 14.04 and then it stopped working. I tried everything I removed the ap-hotspot completely and then again started it but it is not working it gets stuck in "Starting Wireless Hotspot..."

Is there any other way of creating a hotspot in kubuntu.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: In Hardware I am having a i3 3rd gen. processor, Wifi support, 1.9 Ghz processor. what else should I provide friend?